# Need help sorting or grouping using a formula

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, formula

The following formulas are used to determine compliance. i need to sort on the results which is N/A. NO, YES. Any suggestions? i do not get the option to sort or group with this formula. 
below is the main formula. the patient type formula is below

```
IF {Command.BATH_STATUS}='NOT DOCUMENTED' THEN 'NO' else IF {@PATIENT
TYPE}='STANDARD' AND {Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED / GIVEN'  AND
ISNULL({Command.STANDARD_BATH})THEN 'NO' ELSE IF
{Command.BATH_STATUS}='Refused' THEN 'N/A' ELSE IF
{Command.MEAS_VALUE} LIKE '*Refuse*' THEN 'N/A' ELSE IF
{Command.MEAS_VALUE} LIKE '*Contrain*' THEN 'N/A' ELSE IF
{Command.BATH_STATUS}='NOT DOCUMENTED' THEN 'NO' ELSE IF
{Command.BATH_STATUS}='NOT GIVEN' THEN 'NO' ELSE IF
{Command.MEAS_VALUE} LIKE '*Incontinence care*' THEN 'NO' ELSE IF
{Command.MEAS_VALUE} LIKE '*Independent*' THEN 'YES' ELSE IF
{Command.MEAS_VALUE} = 'NOT GIVEN' THEN 'NO' ELSE IF{@PATIENT
TYPE}='STANDARD' AND {Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED / GIVEN'  AND
{Command.STANDARD_BATH} ='Standard bathing wipes' THEN 'YES' ELSE
IF{@PATIENT TYPE}='STANDARD' AND {Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED /
GIVEN' AND NOT ISNULL({Command.STANDARD_BATH})THEN 'YES' ELSE
IF{@PATIENT TYPE}='STANDARD' AND {Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED /
GIVEN' AND NOT ISNULL({Command.STANDARD_BATH})  AND NOT
ISNULL({Command.CHG})THEN 'YES' ELSE IF{@PATIENT TYPE}='STANDARD' AND
{Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED / GIVEN' AND NOT
ISNULL({Command.STANDARD_BATH})  AND ISNULL({Command.CHG})THEN 'YES'
ELSE IF{@PATIENT TYPE}='CHG' AND {Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED /
GIVEN' AND NOT ISNULL({Command.STANDARD_BATH})  AND NOT
ISNULL({Command.CHG})THEN 'YES' ELSE IF{@PATIENT TYPE}='CHG' AND
{Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED / GIVEN' AND NOT
ISNULL({Command.CHG})THEN 'YES' ELSE IF{@PATIENT TYPE}='STANDARD' AND
{Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED / GIVEN' AND
ISNULL({Command.STANDARD_BATH}) THEN 'NO' ELSE IF{@PATIENT
TYPE}='CHG' AND {Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED / GIVEN' AND
{Command.STANDARD_BATH} ='Standard bathing wipes'  AND
ISNULL({Command.CHG}) THEN 'NO' ELSE IF{@PATIENT TYPE}='STANDARD' AND
{Command.BATH_STATUS}='WASHED / GIVEN' AND
ISNULL({Command.STANDARD_BATH}) THEN 'NO'
```

the PATIENT TYPE formula is

```
IF {Command.DEPARTMENT_ID} IN [2133009,4313023,4313015,4313016,4314007,4314009,4314027,5119219,5119221,5115578,73,5115579,5119222,5123216,
5133207,5119223,5101202,5133026,5119220,5120202,5119218,5119235] THEN 'CHG'
ELSE
IF NOT ISNULL({Command.IP_LDA_ID_A}) THEN Minimum 
({Command.CL_PATIENT_TYPE_A}, {Command.Y_MRN})
ELSE
{Command.RM_PATIENT_TYPE}
```

i tried to use

```
if {@compliance} = 'n/a' then 1 
  else 
if {@compliance} = 'no' then 2 
  else 
if {@compliance} = 'yes' then 3
```

i still cant use that either.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what the question is but if you are trying to group based on the result of the formula, you can do it as follows:

Insert > Group > Select your formula from the drop down menu and the order it as expected.

Comment: it was able to do in the code by changing the way it was set up. thank you.